# JSTL for display purposes

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

is JSTL core/functions are only for display purposes? like javascript can't it be used to display to a input field instead of mixing javascript and JSTL.

when i try to fill a select element with options i ended up with this.

```
function fill(){

var select=document.getElementById("sel");

<c:foreach items="${value}" var="op">

var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text='${op.optionname}';

select.add(option);

</c:foreach>

}
```

what i am trying to do here is to fill a select element with options when a button is clicked.is there a way to achieve this using only jstl? i am a bit confuse using jstl.

Answer (score 0):

> is JSTL core/functions are only for display purposes?

Generally speaking, yes.

You don't need JavaScript when your JSTL is being proccessed on the server.  You could do this like:

```
<select>
  <c:forEach items="${value}" var="op">
    <option value="${op.optionname}">${op.optionname}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Note also that depending on which framework you're using, it may provide an easy way for your Java objects to back HTML form fields like select lists or input boxes.  Spring MVC has an expanded set of tags to do this, but you can mix regular HTML and JSTL with no problems.

Javascript in JSTL will be ignored by the server and only executed on the client side (i.e. the end user's computer), by that time the server will have taken the JSTL and rendered into HTML (or whatever else you're returning).

So, if you want to dynamically populate the list when a user clicks on something, you'll need to use pure JavaScript and not JSTL, since JSTL is only processed on the server side.

You could potentially combine the two approaches using something like this:

```
<div id="hidden-div" style="display:none">
  <select>
    <c:forEach items="${value}" var="op">
      <option value="${op.optionname}">${op.optionname}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
</div>
```

and then add a jQuery click listener to the button you want the user to click before showing the list:

```
$('#special-button').on('click', function(e){
  $('#hidden-div').show();
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but i am having difficulties because the values that i need to put in a select element dynamically is stored in a request scope. BTW i am using struts framework

Comment: Why not add them to the DOM in the JSTL when they're accessible via the request scope but just not show them until the user clicks on the button that populates the list? Put them in a hidden `div` element, for example.

Comment: what do you  mean by put them in a hidden div and populate the list when a user clicks a button?sorry i am just new in java ee

Comment: See my edit for an example of one way you could do it.

Comment: so it means that if i have a hashmap stored in a reuqestscope and every element of the hashmap contains an arraylist i need to make a divs equivalent to the size of the hashmap and put a select element every div?am i right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this .

```
function fill(){ 
  var select=document.getElementById("sel"); 
  var options = [<c:foreachitems="${value}" var="op">'${op.optionname}',</c:foreach>];  
  $(options).map(function(index,optionValue){ 
      var option=document.createElement("option");
      option.text = optionValue; 
      select.add(option); 
  }); 
}
```